# (Array Parser) token parsing flex/bison strange behaviour

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I am currently trying to parse arrays from a parser i wrote with Flex and Bison.

for example if i input "int testarr[90];" the flex parser correctly match the array identifier "testarr" but when the token is returned to Bison the corresponding token (%token ID) return the string "testarr[90]". How is that possible?

Flex interested part of code (regexp rules)

```
%%

letter  [a-z]
digit   [0-9]
char    [_]

%%
    /* rules */
    /* NOTE: If two patterns match the same string the longest match wins. */

[ \t]                                                  ; /* ignore whitespace and tabs */
[-+*=/\n]                                              return *yytext; /* match operators */
int|float|double                                       { yylval.stringValue = yytext; return TYPE; } /* match array types */
{digit}+                                               { yylval.intValue = atoi(yytext); return NUM; } /* match array indexes or integers */
{digit}+(\.?{digit})+                                  { yylval.doubleValue = atof(yytext); return DECIMAL; } /* match any decimal number (double, float) */

// Here the yytext is "testarr"
{letter}({letter}|{digit})*                            { yylval.stringValue = yytext; return ID; } /* match array identifier (name) */


"["                                                    return yytext[0]; /* match [ */
"]"                                                    return yytext[0]; /* match ] */
";"                                                    return yytext[0]; /* match ; */
","                                                    return yytext[0]; /* match , */
.                                                      return yytext[0]; /* match any other character */

%%
```

here's the Bison part where I get "testarr[90]" instead of "testarr" as token ID.

```
[...other code]

%union
{
    int intValue;
    double doubleValue;
    char *stringValue;
}

%error-verbose
%token TYPE NUM ID DECIMAL

%type <stringValue> TYPE
%type <doubleValue> DECIMAL
%type <intValue>    NUM
%type <stringValue> ID    
%type <doubleValue> E

[...other code and rules]

// here output from printf is "testarr[90]" instead of "testarr"
ARRAY:      ID '[' NUM ']'   { printf("%s", $<stringValue>1); exit(1); };
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to `strcpy` the `yytext` because scanning the next token will invalidate the old pointer (or rather it will move the terminating `\0` past the end of the next token).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. As previously mentioned, there is a duplicated question for this problem here -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151570/why-does-this-bison-code-produce-unexpected-output) and the solution was correct, just corrected `yylval.stringValue = yytext` to `yylval.stringValue = strdup(yytext)` on the lex part and the problem is fixed. Thank you for your help.