# Unexpected value in yytext in production rule for function declaration

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I'm writing a compiler with flex and bison for a college assignment. I'm having trouble adding a function identifier to my symbol table - when evaluating a function declaration I'm getting the opening parenthesis in `yytext` where I'd expect the identifier. In my flex file I have, where `yylval` is an union and `vlex` is a `struct`:

```
abc         [A-Za-z_]
alphanum    [A-Za-z_0-9]
id          {abc}+{alphanum}*

...

#define STORE_YYLVAL_NONE\
  do{\
    ... // location control irrelevant to the problem
    yylval.vlex.type = none_t;\
    yylval.vlex.value.sValue = yytext;\
  }while(0)

...

{id} {
  LOG_DEBUG("id: %s\n", yytext);
  STORE_YYLVAL_NONE;
  return TK_IDENTIFIER;
}

[,;:()\[\]\{\}\+\-\*/<>!&=%#\^\.\|\?\$] {
  LOG_DEBUG("special\n");
  STORE_YYLVAL_NONE;
  return *yytext;
}

...
```

And in my bison file I have:

```
new_identifier_with_node: TK_IDENTIFIER {
  hshsym_add_or_exit(&hshsym, yylval.vlex.value.sValue, &(yylval.vlex));
  $$ = ast_node_create(&(yylval.vlex));
};

func: type new_identifier_with_node '(' param_list ')' func_block { ... };
```

I also have a log inside `hshsym_add_or_exit`, which adds an identifier to my symbol table. When parsing the following program:

```
int k(int x,int y, int z){}
int f(){
        k(10,20,30);
}
```

I'm getting the following debug output:

```
yylex: DEBUG! id: k
yylex: DEBUG! special
hshsym_add_or_exit: DEBUG! Declaring: (
```

That is, when the `new_identifier_with_node` production is evaluated, the content of `yytext` is `(` instead of `k`, as I would expect. Is the code above the cause? I have some still unresolved shift/reduce conflicts which I guess could be at fault, but I don't see how in this specific case. I believe I'm missing something really basic but I can't see what. The project is quite large (and shamefully disorganized) at this point, but I can provide a complete and reproducible example if need be.

Comment: You might find that using bison's built-in trace facility provides a lot more useful information than rolling your own debugging macros. It's certainly less work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is that you are using `yylval` in the `new_identifier_with_node` production, instead of `$1`. `$1` is the semantic value of the first symbol in the production, in this case `TK_IDENTIFIER`.

In a bison action, `yylval` is usually the value of lookahead token, which is the *next* token in the input stream. That's why it shows up as a parenthesis in this case. But you cannot in general count on that because bison will perform a default reduction before reading the lookahead token. In general, using `yylval` in a bison action is very rarely useful, aside from some applications in error recovery.

Even after you fix that, you will find that the semantic values are incorrect because your flex action is forwarding a pointer to an internal data buffer rather than copying the token string. See, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151570/why-does-this-bison-code-produce-unexpected-output).