# Yacc Yytext is overwritten?

Tags: c, yacc, lex

**solution is mentioned in the comments below the post**
I am running into an issue where I have a statement such as 
**i = ary[4];**

lex prints out "ary", however yacc for some reason prints out '[' which means that yytext is being overwritten somehow.

Would someone tell me how to clean up this problem? As soon as I take out

```
PStmt         : Id '[' Expr ']'                                             { $$ = doRary($1, $3); };
```

then my program doesn't have problems, but I can't read arrays anymore.

In my lex file I have:

```
{letter}({letter}|{digit})*   { return Ident; }
{digit}{digit}*                 { return IntLit; }
...
\[                            { return '['; }
\]                                  { return ']'; }
...
```

[Updated: I had to remove this section]
In my yacc file I have:

I would appreciate any tips/solutions as to how to deal with this as the aforementioned statement seems to influence other parts of the grammar.

FYI: I am following C precedence rules.

Answer (score 1):

`yytext` is an internal buffer which belongs to the scanner generated by (f)lex, and its contents are modified on every call to `yylex()`. The bison/yacc-generated parser calls `yylex()` at unpredictable moments. In particular, it will call `yylex()` in order to obtain the lookahead token, which is not part of the current production.

So `yytext` should not be used outside of lexer actions. If the string value of the scanned token will be required by the parser, the lexer action for that token must make a copy of yytext and store it into the appropriate member of `yylval` so that it is available in parser actions involving that token. (See the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Token-Values) for more details.)

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151570/why-does-this-bison-code-produce-unexpected-output), and many others.

Comment: May I ask, would I do something like this in my lex file?  ``` { yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return Ident; } ```  then in the yacc file where I have $$ = doRval(yytext);  it should be $$ = doRval(yylval.str);

Comment: @NoobieProgrammer: In your parser, you don't refer to yylval for the same reason you don't refer to yytext (it doesn't refer to the token you think it refers to). You just use `$1` (or whatever the index of the token in the production's right-hand side is). I'm sure that's visible in the examples in the bison manual.

Comment: Hey thank you for your help. I don't have enough reputation to upvote your comment.  Interestingly enough,  yylval.str  for terminals worked and $1 worked for nonterminals that ended up using yylval.str.   So thank you again!!!